# import class definitions from node_modules index.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, node-modules, typescript-typings

My project has the package "diagram-js" in its node_modules. The file `node_modules/diagram-js/lib/model/index.js` has several class definitions like this:

```
/**
 * @namespace djs.model
 */

/**
 * @memberOf djs.model
 */

/**
 * The basic graphical representation
 *
 * @class
 *
 * @abstract
 */
export function Base() { ... }
```

I've tried making these classes importable in my project with intellisense in the following way:

1. created the file `@types\diagram-js\lib\model\index.d.ts`
2. tried any of the following syntaxes:

```
export module 'diagram-js/lib/model' { ... }
export namespace djs.model { ... }
export declare namespace djs.model { ... }
```

in all cases the outermost block contains the class definitions like this:

```
  declare class Base {
    id: string;
    type: string;
    businessObject: any;
    label: Object;
    parent: Shape;
    labels: Array<Label>;
    outgoing: Array<Connection>;
    incoming: Array<Connection>;
  }
```

I've also tried `declare module` and within it `export class`, but while this worked with other files that weren't `index.js`, in this case intellisense can't seem to find these classes.

Currently I'm using the `namespace` solution but the imports look like `../../../../@types/diagram-js/lib/model` which is not what I want.

What's the right way to expose these classes in my codebase and get intellisense?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all I needed to do was add the folder the `index.d.ts` file was in to the `typeRoots` property in `tsconfig`. For files with names other than `index.js` the process is different, which is what confused me.